# Convert Recursive Python Generator Function to Non Generator Function

Tags: python, recursion, generator, yield

I have the following function in Python, and I want to convert it into a more vanilla function that does not use `yield` so I can translate it to other languages.

Could someone please explain how I could go about this?

The function simply prints out the permutations of `n` choose `m`.

i.e. for `n==4`, `m==2`, it will create arrays of the form:

`1001`, `1100`, `1010` and so on.

```
def bitmasks(n, m):
    if n == m:
        yield (1 << n) - 1
    elif m > 0:
        for x in bitmasks(n-1, m-1):
            yield (1 << (n-1)) + x
        for x in bitmasks(n-1, m):
            yield x
    else:
        yield 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your results to a list.

```python
def bitmasks(n, m):
    if n == m:
        return [(1 << n) - 1]
    elif m > 0:
        res = []
        for x in bitmasks(n-1, m-1):
            res.append((1 << (n-1)) + x)
        for x in bitmasks(n-1, m):
            res.append(x)
        return res
    else:
        return [0]
```

Answer (score 2):

The function does not print anything, it just yields each result piece by piece. You can create an empty list in the beginning and then replace each `yield` by an `append` to your list. In the end, you just return the full list of results.